# Translation group of a discrete group - what am I missing?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a discrete group, then its translation group $L_G$ is the set of vectors $a$ such that $t_a \in G$. Since $t_at_b=t_{a+b}$ and $t_{-a}={t_a}^{-1}$  ... (in Page 167 of the 1st edition of Artin's Algebra)

But how is $t_{a+b}$ always in $G$? For example if $|a|=\varepsilon$ and $|b|=\frac {3\varepsilon}{2}$ then $|a+b|$ can be $\frac {\varepsilon}{2}$ so it looks like for any $\varepsilon$ we can always find $t_x$ with $|x|<\varepsilon$

EDIT: Apologies if my question was not clear enough. I did find an answer to my question which is part of the proof of the theorem that follows later in the text. Obviously having $|a+b|<\varepsilon$ is a contradiction if $G$ is a discrete group and my question was how we avoid that. The theorem states that a discrete subgroup $L$ of $\mathbb R^2$ has restricted forms (either $L={0}$ or $L=\{ma \mid m \in \mathbb Z\}$ or $L=\{ma+nb \mid m,n \in \mathbb Z\}$).

Comment: maybe $t_a:G\to G$ is defined by $t_a(x)=x+a$

Comment: take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)

Comment: meanwhile, I'm going to post an answer and if this is not what you seek, I will delete it

Comment: @janmarqz I'm very tired and going to bed now but I promise to read your answer tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: ok friend, take a rest

Comment: you are saying $G$ is discrete *group*; so when $t_a,t_b$ is in $G$, then $t_{a+b}=t_at_b$ should be in $G$; what is your exact question?